# Silverlight 4 : Converting image into byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, image, silverlight-4.0

I have found how to do this in .NET 4.0, but I think JpegBitmapEncoder doesn't exist in Silverlight:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();              
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageC));
encoder.Save(memStream);
var bytes = memStream.GetBuffer();
```

How can I convert an image to bytes[] in silverlight?

**UPDATE:**

I have a Contact model, which has a Photo property. Whenever I add a new Contact, I would like to load a local default Image and convert it and set the Photo property to it.

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage
                            {
                                UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/xxx;component/Images/default.JPG")
                            };
            var image = new Image{Source = bitmapImage};
```

Is this the correct way to load an image in first place?

Comment: It probably does exist, but you'll need to add the correct reference to use it. And I wouldn't know which one.

Comment: No mate. This doesn't exist in Silverlight.

Comment: Nevermind, this is just for WPF not Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this library: [Imagetools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/)

It contains some nice utilities and jpg and png encoders,

Comment: Erno, neat solutionm but even using an ExtendedImage from that library, how does it help me to convert the image into byte[] ?

Comment: This encoders are indeed essential. I got it finally working.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
myImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
return memStream.ToArray();
```

---

### UPDATE

OK it turns out that the image is a `BitmapImage`.

It seems that `BitmapImage` does not expose the functionality to save the image. The solution is to get the image from the embedded resource:

```
Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];
s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Please see my update, I don't see the Save() method in image, unless I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Well, as I posted it above it is a .JPG

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how your solution should work. Your Image is from System.Drawing.Image namespace. From my understanding you don't even have that in Silverlight.

Comment: Try this solution I posted. Use the path not in the silverlight fromat but in the namespace format.

Comment: I tried this without success: Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("../Images/default.JPG");
If my URi to the picture is like this, what should I be putting in there? "pack://application:,,,/xxx;component/Images/default.JPG" Th erelative path didnt work :(

Comment: No you need to see what URL it has within the assembly. Normally it is `<AssemblyName>.Images.default.JPG` so paths are joined by dot and not slash.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757/how-can-i-discover-the-path-of-an-embedded-resource

Comment: I feel now quite stupid. But I dont get it work: Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("SalesContactManagement.Modules.NavigationModule.Images.default.JPG");

I am expecting to see the path when I type it directly in code: SalesContactManagement.Modules.NavigationModule.Images The Images can't be found. I have set the default image to Embedded Resource and tested it also as Resource. No luck...

Comment: Use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` to see all the names and then copy the path you need to use.