# How to get the String Resources from a dll file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resources, embedded-resource

In VS 2010, .Net 4.0
I am trying to get the names of all the string resources in a given dll
The ultimate goal is, from a set of files, to be able to get all the resources, check which ones are Strings, and test the names to see if they have the key words I am looking for.
The main point is: I have only the dll file, nothing else.
Let say my file name is

```
    Dim myDllFullFileName as string = "C:\Bob.dll"
```

First, I guess I should get the Reflection :

```
    Dim myAssembly As New Reflection.Assembly 
    myAssembly=Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(myDllFullFileName)
```

Then the problems begin.
If I was simply looking for the string resources in my current project I could do that:

```
   Dim myResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet 
   myResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
   For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In myResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
            If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is String Then
                If Dict.Key.ToString.Contains("myOwnKeyHere") Then
                    'work with dict.value'
                End If
            End If
    Next
```

This would work fine for my current project. And the results are exactly what I am looking for.
My problem is that I want to do it with the dll files.
I think I should be able to built a ResourSet from myAssembly. For that, I will need a ResourceManager.
To build a new ResourceManager from myAssembly, I should probably use this method:

```
Public Sub New(baseName As String, assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly)
```

And that's where I am lost: I don't manage to get the baseName from the dll file that I am using.


I also try to with

```
 myAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

But it is return an empty array

If anyone has an idea, I would greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757/how-can-i-discover-the-path-of-an-embedded-resource are you 100% sure that your are loading the dll correctly and that it does contain ewmbedded resources?

Comment: I am sure that I have embedded resources (in an resx file). The Resources are also set to PUBLIC and not Friend. Now I am not 100% sure that I am loading the dll correctly, but I think so, as I can execute this: myAssembly.GetTypes for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is one answer:
I want to get the Name and Value of all the Resource String that are in a .dll or a .resx or a .exe file.

```
    Dim myDllFullFileName As String = "C:\Bob.dll"
    'it will also work for .resx and .exe files'
    Dim myAssembly As Reflection.Assembly
    myAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(myDllFullFileName)
    Dim myBaseNames(-1) As String
    myBaseNames = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames
    Dim myResourcesBaseName As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To myBaseNames.Length - 1
        If myBaseNames(i).Contains(".Resources.") Then
            myResourcesBaseName = myBaseNames(i)
            'in the case of a .exe file, you will get more than one file'
            'Example with an .exe file from a Windows Application having one form:'
            'WindowsApplication1.Form1.resources'
            'WindowsApplication1.Resources.resources'
            'you want the one containing ".Resources."'
        End If
    Next
    myResourcesBaseName = myResourcesBaseName.Substring(0, myResourcesBaseName.LastIndexOf("."))
    'then you cut the last part and keep "WindowsApplication1.Resources"'

    Dim myManager As System.Resources.ResourceManager
    myManager = New System.Resources.ResourceManager(myResourcesBaseName, myAssembly)

    Dim myResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet = Nothing
    myResourceSet = myManager.GetResourceSet(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True) 'the second true (tryparent, is vital)'
    Dim myResourceNames(-1) As String
    Dim myResourceValues(-1) As String
    If myResourceSet IsNot Nothing Then
        myResourceNames = GetStringRessources(myResourceSet) 'see below for this routine'
        ReDim myResourceValues(myResourceNames.Length - 1)
        For i As Integer = 0 To myResourceNames.Length - 1
            myResourceValues(i) = myResourceSet.GetString(myResourceNames(i))
        Next
    End If
```

Here is the routine GetRessources:

```
 Public Function GetStringRessources(valResourceSet As ResourceSet) As String()
    Dim myList(-1) As String
    For Each Dict As DictionaryEntry In valResourceSet.OfType(Of Object)()
        If TypeOf (Dict.Value) Is String Then
            ReDim Preserve myList(myList.Length)
            myList(myList.Length - 1) = Dict.Key.ToString
        End If
    Next
    Return myList
End Function
```

This enables me to store the name and the value of all the resources strings.

You need to be careful about the following things:
-the code above will also return the content of TEXT files (they must be considered as strings as well, I suppose). So if you don't want the text of the files, and you expect strings of a certain length, a simple test is possible. Otherwise, I am not sure how to solve the problem.