# Getting path to subproject's Content folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, document-root, server.mappath, subproject

Currently I have a main (root) ASP.NET MVC project that sits at the base, while all the subprojects are added as references. I'd like to use the subproject's **Content** folder, but unfortunately `Server.MapPath`, and `Content.Url` keeps giving me the **root project**'s **Content** folder, and not the subproject's **Content** folder (which is where the items are output to).

I've searched quite a bit around Stack Overflow but it seems that majority of the people are trying to find the path to the main project, which is not what I want. I'm calling this method from one of the subproject's Controllers.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009891/how-can-i-use-server-mappath-inside-class-library-project)  hope this helps

Comment: Have you defined your subprojects as their own web applications with their own worker processes in IIS?  or are they just in folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a url of sub project like this

```
filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

destinationPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), filename);

string url = "http://localhost:4334/ImageUpload/ImageUploadSub/?imagename=" + filename + "&imagepath=" + destinationPath;
```