# VSIX: Added item doesn't get copied in vsix installation folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I need to run a perl script from within vsix.

1. I have created a vsix package and added existing item 'test.pl'
2. I moved it under 'Resource' folder and also changed its property to 'Embedded Resource' and 'Do not copy'.

I access this .pl in the code using `GetManifestResourceNames()` and execute it. When I build the project, test.pl gets created in bin/debug and bin/release folder. I am using streamToOutputFile code to do that.

**First question is** - Is this a right way to embed third party script or say exe in vsix project?

Actual problem started when I **installed vsix** and started using it.
My vsix package folder gets created under *%LocalAppData%\..\Extensions* but test.pl wasn't present there.

Also when I ran extn from VS, it threw an error - 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\test.pl' is denied.'

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: This article helped me to fix my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757/how-can-i-discover-the-path-of-an-embedded-resource