# MVC 5 Sitemap Provider Localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

MVC 5 Sitemap Provider

How can i give the node title from a resource key in a file which is in an external project.

I do not plan to use external DI. Please tell me if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

At present, the [only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126620/globalization-in-mvcsitemapprovider/25139596#25139596) requires using an external DI container. However, we are [gathering requirements to make a new extension point to provide localization from external assemblies](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/344), and your feedback is most welcome.