# Resource issue in multi project asp.net solution

Tags: asp.net

I have a multi project solution for an *asp.net* website. There is DAL, BLL and entity projects all shared with another application and a resources project for strings (to support multiple languages).

The resource is set to public. `Common.Resources` is the both the project name and the namespace. `Strings` is the Resource file. Accessing the resources in code after referencing the project is easy

```
Common.Resources.Strings.[MyResourceStringNameHere]
```

The issue is I need to access the resource strings in the sitemap and in literal html tags doesn't work. Examples of what i have tried below.

```
$Resources:Strings, [MyResourceStringNameHere]
$Resources:Common.Resources.Strings, [MyResourceStringNameHere]
```

Much searching has led me to believe that I may need a resource manager to bring in the resources from the other project. All examples are aimed towards a *SQL* resource manager so aren't proving particularly helpful. 
Any examples, suggestions, etc would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's nice example of sitemap globalization for ASP.NET Core using external resources:
[Globalization in MVCSiteMapProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126620/globalization-in-mvcsitemapprovider/25139596#25139596)

If project does not use ASP .NET Core, you can follow instructions in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx#exaspnet20rpm_topic5

Basically, you need to create custom `ResourceProviderFactory` which should return yours implementation of `IResourceProvider` where you can handle external resources.

Comment: Great thank you. I will work though the example. Unfortunately the links to source code are missing but I should be able to work it through.

Comment: You can check out this repository for example implementation: https://github.com/DynamicTyped/Bocce/tree/master/Bocce