# C# How to get the PATH of the embedded .exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**I have an exe file which I run through windows command prompt and give command line arguments**. I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757/how-can-i-discover-the-path-of-an-embedded-resource) and ran the following command:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

But all it did, is to give me resource files located in WindowsFormsApplication1\obj\Debug folder

I went through  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program)  but it tells on how to execute the exe directly without the running it from cmd.

I even tried the following command:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "MyApplication.exe");
```

It worked but after clearing my C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp folder the application started giving an error.

I even tried the following command:

```
global::ApplicationName.Properties.Resources.MyApplication
```

but it gives byte[] and not the path to the application.

All I want to know is how to run the application which is embedded in my resources so that I can successfully execute the following command:

```
var proc = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            FileName = "cmd.exe",
                            Arguments = "/K " + MyApplication+" Argument "+Path1+" "+Path2 ,
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            CreateNoWindow = true
                        }
                    };
                    proc.Start();

                    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                    {

                        string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(resultFile))
                        {
                            file.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You have an embedded file as a resource in your project? If so you must extract it to a directory in the filsystem before you run it.

Comment: Yes I have added the application file as a resource. How do I extract it and run it then ? Can i delete it after running it so that the application does not create any temporary junk files ?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the resource into a file in the filesystem and then run it.

```
byte[] fileContents = ApplicationName.Properties.Resources.MyApplication;
File.WriteAllBytes("MyApplication.exe", fileContents);
```

Now you can run the file using MyApplicaton.exe as path.

Comment: I tried the following command:    byte[] fileContents =global::ApplicationName.Properties.Resources.MyApplication;
            File.WriteAllBytes("MyApplication.exe", fileContents);
            MessageBox.Show(MyApplication.exe); but it gives me error

Comment: Why are you doing messagebox cloc.exe? The code fragment i have written creates a file in the current directory so you can run it using process.start

Comment: I don't want to run the application as it is. i want to run it through command line so i can give it arguments. I did MessageBox.Show to see if it's giving me the path

Comment: Ok so use a full path of your choice to extract your executable and then pass the same path to the cmd

Comment: I am a beginner to C# could you please explain me how to do that

Comment: Just run the what @Priyanka suggested, and see if it created a file in the current directory (current of the running `.exe`, perhaps `\bin\Debug\` of your project). If it does, run your code, but you don't need to run `cmd.exe` you can run the `"MyApplication.exe"` and pass it the arguments (you already have most of the code written in your question...