# How to compile (.ppt, excel) resources into .exe?

Tags: c#, vb.net, resources, office-interop

I have three excel and one powerpoint file that I need in my `Windows Forms Application`. My goal is that they will be compiled into the exe, so the tool can be used from anywhere without dependencies to our LAN folders. 
I already tried to drop them into the Resources-Folder in the solution explorer but using them afterwards I have a path like `(Z://yourexelfile.xlsx)`. Second thought was to add them as resources in the P`roject->Properties->Ressources` and access them afterwards via `MyProject.My.Resources.Template` but this does not work as well since my functions need a "String" (in this case a path) in the constructor. I tried [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757/how-can-i-discover-the-path-of-an-embedded-resource) but this does not give me the needed path just something like MyApp.Resources.resources. It would be great if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: You can read the files bytes, hardcode the bytes into the code, and write them to a temp file when you want to use the files on runtime. Silly idea, but simple to do, considering only 3 files are at hand.

Comment: @YoryeNathan rather than hardcoding, adding files to Properties/Resources allows just that, to get them as a byte[].

Comment: @NLindbom That's pretty neat. Who thought of that?! :3